# SQL query to group by age range from date created

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get statistics with sql query. My table is like this:

```
ID MATERIAL CREATEDATE DEPARTMENT
1  M1       10.10.1980 D1
2  M2       11.02.1970 D2
2  M3       18.04.1971 D3
.....................
.....................
.....................
```

How can I get a range of data count like this

```
DEPARTMENT AGE<10  10<AGE<20 20<AGE
D1         24       123      324
D2         24       123      324
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that CREATEDATE is a date column, in PostgreSQL you can use the [AGE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html) function:

```
select DEPARTMENT, age(CREATEDATE) as AGE
from Materials
```

and with date_part you can get the age in years. To show the data in the format that you want, you could use this GROUP BY query:

```
select
  DEPARTMENT,
  sum(case when date_part('year', age(CREATEDATE))<10 then 1 end) as "age<10",
  sum(case when date_part('year', age(CREATEDATE))>=10 and date_part('year', age(CREATEDATE))<20 then 1 end) as "10<age<20",
  sum(case when date_part('year', age(CREATEDATE))>=20 then 1 end) as "20<age"
from
  Materials
group by
  DEPARTMENT
```

which can be simplified as:

```
with mat_age as (
  select DEPARTMENT, date_part('year', age(CREATEDATE)) as mage
  from Materials
)
select
  DEPARTMENT,
  sum(case when mage<10 then 1 end) as "age<10",
  sum(case when mage>=10 and mage<20 then 1 end) as "10<age<20",
  sum(case when mage>=20 then 1 end) as "20<age"
from
  mat_age
group by
  DEPARTMENT;
```

if you are using PostgreSQL 9.4 you can use FILTER:

```
with mat_age as (
  select DEPARTMENT, date_part('year', age(CREATEDATE)) as mage
  from Materials
)
select
  DEPARTMENT,
  count(*) filter (where mage<10) as "age<10",
  count(*) filter (where mage>=10 and mage<20) as "10<age<20",
  count(*) filter (where mage>=20) as "20<age"
from
  mat_age
group by
  DEPARTMENT;
```

Comment: This answer was posted 15 minutes after mine and is largely identical to what I posted.  It is inconceivable that you did not read my answer before posting.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using the AGE function which you didn't use, I'm using CTE which you didn't use, and I'm using FILTER which is new to PostgreSQL 9.4 ... I'm also skipping the `ELSE 0` part because it's not needed and you were using ' instead of " ... it's not largely identical

Answer (score 2):

The following solution assumes that your `CREATEDATE` column exists as some sort of valid Postgres date type.  If this be not the case, and it is being stored as text, you will first have to convert it to date in order for the query to work.

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(year, CREATEDATE, now()::date) < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "AGE<10",
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(year, CREATEDATE, now()::date) >= 10 AND
             DATEDIFF(year, CREATEDATE, now()::date) < 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "10<AGE<20",
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(year, CREATEDATE, now()::date) >= 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "20<AGE"
FROM Materials
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT
```

Comment: A small correction use `"` instead of `'` for table alias !

Comment: @wingedpanther You truly are king of beasts :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extract(year FROM age(createdate))` to get the exact age

i.e

```
select extract(year FROM age(timestamp '01-01-1989')) age
```

will give you

Result:

```
age
---
 27
```

so you can use following select statement to get your desired output:

```
 SELECT dept
    ,sum(CASE  WHEN age < 10THEN 1 END) "age<10"
    ,sum(CASE  WHEN age >= 10  AND age < 20 THEN 1 END) "10<age<20"
    ,sum(CASE WHEN age >= 20 THEN 1 END) "20<age"
FROM (
    SELECT dept,extract(year FROM age(crdate)) age
    FROM dt
    ) t
GROUP BY dept
```

If you don't want to use a sub select use this.

```
SELECT dept
    ,sum(CASE  WHEN extract(year FROM age(crdate)) < 10THEN 1 END) "age<10"
    ,sum(CASE  WHEN extract(year FROM age(crdate)) >= 10  AND extract(year FROM age(crdate)) < 20 THEN 1 END) "10<age<20"
    ,sum(CASE WHEN extract(year FROM age(crdate)) >= 20 THEN 1 END) "20<age"
FROM dt
GROUP BY dept
```

Comment: When using an ANSI SQL timestamp literal it's better to use an ISO formatted date: `date '1989-01-01'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Noted and thanks for the heads up

Comment: I'm actually surprised that Postgres accepts that, as the SQL standard clearly requires an ISO formatted date and e.g. Oracle will reject `'01-01-1989'`

Comment: `timestamp` came to my mind when I started typing that query..!!